# Integration of Bessel function of the second kind

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, bessel-functions

I need to calculate the below integration;
$$\int Y_0(x) \, dx,$$ where $ Y_0(x) $ is a zero order Bessel function of second kind. 
This seems like a simple integration, however I could nowhere find a solution for this. I tried in Wolform alpha [alpha solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20bessely%280%2Cx%29%20dx), answer comes with Struve functions which I am not familiar with.

Can anyone shed light on this matter.

Comment: I don't know of another form than the Struve function given by alpha (except that you can express the Struve function in terms of the hypergeometric function, see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function)). In the end, if the primitive is a Struve function, it is a Struve function...

Comment: @ mickep thanks alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ask Wolfram Alpha to differentiate what it claims to be an antiderivative of $Y_{0}(x)$, it leaves the result in a messy form.

But you can show that indeed $$\int \text{Y}_{0}(x) \, dx = \frac{\pi x}{2} \Big(Y_{0}(x){\bf H}_{-1}(x)+Y_{1}(x) {\bf H}_{0}(x)\Big) + C \ $$

by using the identities

$$ \frac{d}{dx} {\bf H}_{\alpha}(x) = -\frac{\alpha}{x} \, {\bf H}_{\alpha}(x) + {\bf H}_{\alpha -1}(x) \tag{1}$$

and

$$\frac{d}{dx} {\bf H}_{\alpha}(x) = \frac{\alpha}{x} \, {\bf H}_{\alpha}(x) - {\bf H}_{\alpha +1}(x) + \frac{(\frac{x}{2})^{\alpha}}{\sqrt{\pi} \, \Gamma \left(\alpha + \frac{3}{2} \right)}  \tag{2}$$

which come from adding and subtracting the two recurrence relations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function#Properties).

We also need the fact that for the Bessel function of the second kind (and similarly for the Bessel function of the first kind),

$$\frac{d}{dx} \, Y_{0}(x) = - Y_{1}(x) $$

and

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \, x  Y_{1}(x) = x  Y_{0}(x) .$$

Using $(2)$,

$$ \begin{align} &\frac{d}{dx}  \Big[ x Y_{0}(x){\bf H}_{-1}(x) \Big] \\ &= Y_{0}(x) {\bf H}_{-1}(x) -x Y_{1}(x) {\bf H}_{-1}(x)+ x Y_{0}(x) \left(- \frac{{\bf H}_{-1}(x)}{x} - {\bf H}_{0}(x)+ \frac{(\frac{2}{x})}{\sqrt{\pi} \, \Gamma \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)} \right) \\ &= -xY_{1}(x) {\bf H}_{-1}(x) - x Y_{0}(x) {\bf H}_{0}(x) + \frac{2 Y_{0}(x)}{\pi}. \end{align}$$

And using $(1)$,

$$ \begin{align} \frac{d}{dx} \Big[x \, Y_{1}(x) {\bf H}_{0}(x) \Big] &= xY_{0}(x){\bf H}_{0}(x) + x Y_{1}(x) \Big(0 + {\bf H}_{-1}(x) \Big) \\ &= xY_{0}(x) {\bf H}_{0}(x) + x Y_{1}(x) {\bf H}_{-1}(x) .  \end{align} $$

Therefore,

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \left[\frac{\pi x}{2} \Big(Y_{0}(x){\bf H}_{-1}(x)+Y_{1}(x) {\bf H}_{0}(x)\Big) \right] = \frac{\pi}{2} \left(\frac{2 Y_{0}}{\pi} \right) = Y_{0}(x).$$

Comment: amazing..Thanks heaps